# Problems with JSON visualization in SwiftUI App

Tags: json, swiftui

I'm working on my first app, which loads a JSON with the elements that need to be displayed.
At the moment everything seems to work, except a few details￼ which I hope you can help me solve:

- My interface is composed of a TabView contained within a NavigationView (which contains a button that brings up a SheetView) ... if I go to the Tab that brings up the list with the contents downloaded from the JSON everything works, but if I move to another Tab and then I go back to the one that displays the JSON, the data is no longer visible.
  I obviously inserted in the code (where necessary) ObservableObject, ObservedObject and onAppear that should reload the JSON, but without success ... it is clear that something is missing ...
- How could I go about displaying a list of categories starting from a JSON field? Let me explain, I used the "autore" field of the JSON to define categories, so I would need to first display a list of these categories, then, entering the respective categories, I have to display a list with the elements relating to the selected category and then obviously the DetailView for the single elements.

Of course, since is my first time writing here, ask me everything you need to help me solving the problem...

This is the relevant code:

Code: BussoModel.swift

```
import SwiftUI

class BussoModel: Identifiable {

    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var titolo: String = ""
    var autore: String = ""
    var testo: String = ""
    var data: String = ""
    var extra1: String = ""
    var extra2: String = ""
    var fotoUrl: String = ""
}
```

Code: DownloadManager.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Alamofire

class DownloadManager: ObservableObject {

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var storage : [BussoModel] = []

    func scaricaJSON() {
    
        AF.request("http://geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org/index.php?json=1").responseJSON { response in
        
            if let errore = response.error {
                debugPrint(errore.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        
            guard let ilJson = response.value else { return }
        
            guard let json = JSON(ilJson).array else { return }
        
            self.storage = []
        
            let totale = json.count
        
            for i in 0..<totale {
            
                let busso = BussoModel()
            
                if let titolo = json[i]["titolo"].string {
                    busso.titolo = titolo
                }
            
                if let autore = json[i]["autore"].string {
                    busso.autore = autore
                }
            
                if let testo = json[i]["testo"].string {
                    busso.testo = testo
                }
            
                if let data = json[i]["data"].string {
                    busso.data = data
                }
            
                if let extra1 = json[i]["extra1"].string {
                    busso.extra1 = extra1
                }
            
                if let extra2 = json[i]["extra2"].string {
                    busso.extra2 = extra2
                }
            
                if let foto = json[i]["fotoUrl"].string {
                    busso.fotoUrl = foto
                }
            
                self.storage.append(busso)
            
            }
        
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        
        }
    
    }

}
```

Code: CategoryView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import URLImage

struct CategoryView: View {

    @ObservedObject var dm: DownloadManager

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(dm.storage) { busso in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(busso: busso)) {
                    HStack {
                        URLImage(URL(string: busso.fotoUrl) ?? furl)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .clipped()
                            .padding()
                    
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(busso.titolo)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(busso.autore)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                        }
                    
                        Spacer().layoutPriority(-0.1)
                    
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.dm.scaricaJSON()
        }
    }
}

struct CategoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CategoryView(dm: DownloadManager())
    }
}
```

Code: MainTabView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainTabView: View {

    @State private var selected = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 0 ? "house.fill" :         "house"))
                    Text("Home")
                }.tag(0)
            CategoryView(dm: DownloadManager())
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 1 ? "text.justify" : "text.justify"))
                    Text("Categorie")
                }.tag(1)
            Text("Galleria?")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 2 ? "photo.fill" : "photo"))
                    Text("Galleria")
                }.tag(2)
            Text("Preferiti?")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 3 ? "star.fill" : "star"))
                    Text("Preferiti")
                }.tag(3)
        }
        .accentColor(.white)
        .onAppear() {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 115.0/255.0, green: 90.0/255.0, blue: 143.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 115.0/255.0, green: 90.0/255.0, blue: 143.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}

struct MainTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainTabView()
    }
}
```

Code: ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import URLImage

let furl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "path")

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showInfoView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MainTabView()
                .sheet(isPresented: $showInfoView) {
                    InfoView(showInfoView: $showInfoView)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle((Text("ViviBusso")), displayMode:     .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                        Button(action: {
                                            debugPrint("QR Code")
                                        }) {
                                            Image(systemName: "qrcode")
                                        }
                    .foregroundColor(.white), trailing: Button(action: {
                        self.showInfoView.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Waiting for suggestions, thanks!

EDIT: New code tested:

```
import SwiftUI
import URLImage

struct Busso: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id: UUID
    public var titolo: String
    public var autore: String
    public var testo: String
    public var data: String
    public var extra1: String
    public var extra2: String
    public var foto: String
    public var fotoUrl: String
}

class FetchBusso: ObservableObject {

    @Published var Bussos = [Busso]()
    
    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org/index.php?json=1")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let bussoData = data {

                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Busso].self, from: bussoData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.Bussos = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct CategoryView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchBusso()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetch.Bussos) { todo in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(todo.titolo)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct CategoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CategoryView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ask one question and not two and you need to provide much more details and of course relevant code

Comment: OK, I'll edit the original post so you can get a better idea of what's going on...
As for the two questions, in my opinion they are somehow related to each other, that's why I posted them both...

Comment: I think a great deal of your issue is that you are not properly dealing with your JSON. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65420942/7129318) for a modern, well constructed async fetch. Then look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65418427/7129318) above that details a struct to properly parse the data. This result in the data being in a nice struct for your use. If you still can't make it work at that point, ask a new question and show the code you have. P.S. check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidance on asking questions.

Comment: @Yrb I added my code in the original post, could you please tell me what changes I need to make, and where? Keep in mind, is my first app, so I still don't know a lot of things...

Comment: Part of the learning is beating it into your head. The links I posted in my comment pretty well cover it. The code in the first link is pretty much copy and paste. The second link shows you how to put together the struct for decoding the JSON. It really is all there.

Comment: @Yrb OK, I've tried something similar to the one you linked me (you can find it at the bottom of my original question), and it seems to work; every time I change tab, the list is reloaded from the JSON ... but there is a small problem: it works with all the JSON that I have tried except mine! The only thing that appears is "Error" in console every time I change tab, so I assume that somehow the code works, but it fails to extract the data from my JSON...any suggestions?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "my JSON". Each JSON file is set up in a certain, predictable way. That is why the decoder can decode it with the struct. If you change the JSON structure, you need a new struct to decode it. However, at this point, you really need to ask a new question, rather than keep modifying this one. The reason is that answers are meant to be discrete for the next user to find. When you post the next question, you will need to post a sample of the JSON that you are talking about. I was able to look at the original JSON as you posted a link to it, which works.

Comment: @Yrb Yeah, I’m doing a bit of confusion... By “my JSON” I mean the one that you can see in the last bit of code I added, and (as you said) it works perfectly when I open it in a browser...but I will follow your advice, I will create a new question, with the new code and the link to the JSON I want to use...

Comment: There is no JSON in your code. I think you may mean the JSON decoder, not the actual JSON file. As the decoder works only on a specific format of JSON, you need to provide the actual raw data that you are working with. Make sure that is included in your new question. and read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) carefully. It will help you ask better questions that will be answered quickly.

Comment: @Yrb I’ve just created a new question: I put the Swift code and the link to the JSON file...do you think it’s better to post the entire JSON code than the link?