# JSON list not visible in SwiftUI

Tags: json, list, swiftui

I’m trying to loading the content from a JSON that I created, but unfortunately it doesn’t work.
As you can see from the code below, the only thing I see is “Error” printed in the console.
I also tried with other JSONs from the web, changing the struct accordingly, and it works, but not with the JSON I created.

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import URLImage

struct Busso: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id: UUID
    public var titolo: String
    public var autore: String
    public var testo: String
    public var data: String
    public var extra1: String
    public var extra2: String
    public var foto: String
    public var fotoUrl: String
}

class FetchBusso: ObservableObject {

    @Published var Bussos = [Busso]()
    
    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org/index.php?json=1")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let bussoData = data {

                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Busso].self, from: bussoData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.Bussos = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct CategoryView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchBusso()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetch.Bussos) { todo in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(todo.titolo)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct CategoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CategoryView()
    }
}
```

And here is the link to the JSON I want to use:

https://geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org/index.php?json=1

Waiting for your advice, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is

`public var id: UUID` your JSON is `public var id: String`

```
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

is more useful than

```
print("Error")
```

Comment: Perfect! I spent hours looking for the problem, and in the end it was a stupid thing, but since I'm just starting out, you know...

Answer (score 2):

Json I'm throwing the site to help you read. You can get help at the point where you get stuck.shttps: //app.quicktype.io

Comment: Thank you! Is very useful, surely I'll use in the future...

Answer (score 1):

Your Busso struct is not a proper decoder for the given JSON. As I gave you [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65418427/7129318) to a prior one of my answers that explains how to get a struct that will parse your data. You really need to review that, but for the sake of putting this to bed, the struct should be:

```
// MARK: - GeniuspointfrezzaDecoder
struct GeniuspointfrezzaDecoder: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let titolo: String?
    let autore: String?
    let testo: String?
    let data: String?
    let extra1: String?
    let extra2: String?
    let creazione: String?
    let foto: String?
    let fotoURL: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, titolo, autore, testo, data, extra1, extra2, creazione, foto
        case fotoURL = "fotoUrl"
    }
}
```

I made the elements all optional since you don't actually know if the server response will contain all of the elements. Another issue you had was declaring the `id` in your decoder to be a UUID, when the JSON response is clearly a string. Changing the response data to your app's needs has to be done AFTER decoding the response. The decoder is NOT your Busso struct. It is a decoder that gives you the data to put into your Busso struct.

Comment: Very helpful, especially the optional part...now it works perfectly...thank you very very much!