# How to add Dictionary items to a SwiftUI List respectively

Tags: swift, xcode, api, rest, swiftui

I've been playing around with API's in Swift and would like to know the **most straight forward approach to taking the "brandResults" var and it's indices and putting it inside of a list inside of a view using SwiftUI**.

I am new to SwiftUI so any help would be appreciated.

Check out the code below...

I get a response like:

```
    "results": [
        "ASICS",
        "ADIDAS",
        "AIR JORDAN",
        "ALEXANDER MCQUEEN",
        "BAIT",
        "BALENCIAGA",
        "BURBERRY",
        "CHANEL",
        "COMMON PROJECTS",
        "CONVERSE",
        "CROCS",
        "DIADORA",
        "DIOR",
        "GUCCI",
        "JORDAN",
        "LI-NING",
        "LOUIS VUITTON",
        "NEW BALANCE",
        "NIKE",
        "OFF-WHITE",
        "OTHER",
        "PRADA",
        "PUMA",
        "REEBOK",
        "SAINT LAURENT",
        "SAUCONY",
        "UNDER ARMOUR",
        "VANS",
        "VERSACE",
        "YEEZY"
    ]
}
```

I have struct/model like this:

```
struct Brands:  Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let results: [String]
}
```

I have a viewmodel that makes a request and converts into a dictionary:

```
    @Published var brandResults = [Brands]()
  
    func fetch(completion: @escaping ([Brands]) -> ()) {
        
        //Setup the request
        let url = URL(string: "https://v1-.p.rapidapi.com/v1/")
        guard let requestUrl = url else {return}
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("x-rapidapi-host", forHTTPHeaderField: "")
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["x-rapidapi-key":""]
        

        //Convert to object
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
            
        do {
            if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as?
                NSDictionary {
                print("Converted JSON to Dictionary \(convertedJsonIntoDict)")
            }
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        

        //Parse
        guard let data = data else {return}
        let brandResult = self.parseJSON(data: data)
        
        //Brand results has the list of brands that I need
        guard let brandResults = brandResult else {return}
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func parseJSON(data: Data) -> Brands? {
        var returnValue: Brands?
        do {
            returnValue = try JSONDecoder().decode(Brands.self, from: data) } catch {
                print("")
            }
        return returnValue
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find [both answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417381/json-file-is-missing-struct-is-wrong/65418427#65418427) helpful. The code you posted is a bit out of date. Also, rather than force unwrap your `data`, you should use a `guard` or `if let` to unwrap it, otherwise you could crash your app. Avoid using `!` unless you are absolutely positive the variable won't be nil.

Comment: And there is little point in having a struct that only contains an array of strings and certainly no point in making it Identifiable since you will have only one of it. So either extract the array of strings and keep that or decode directly into a [String: [String]] and keep the dictionary values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for you:

```
let stringOfJSON = """
{
"results": [
    "ASICS",
    "ADIDAS",
    "AIR JORDAN",
    "ALEXANDER MCQUEEN",
    "BAIT",
    "BALENCIAGA",
    "BURBERRY",
    "CHANEL",
    "COMMON PROJECTS",
    "CONVERSE",
    "CROCS",
    "DIADORA",
    "DIOR",
    "GUCCI",
    "JORDAN",
    "LI-NING",
    "LOUIS VUITTON",
    "NEW BALANCE",
    "NIKE",
    "OFF-WHITE",
    "OTHER",
    "PRADA",
    "PUMA",
    "REEBOK",
    "SAINT LAURENT",
    "SAUCONY",
    "UNDER ARMOUR",
    "VANS",
    "VERSACE",
    "YEEZY"
]
}
"""

struct Brand: Decodable {
    var results: [String]
}


let dataOfJSON: Data? = stringOfJSON.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


func decoderFunction<T: Decodable>(dataOfJSON: Data?, decodedValue: (T) -> Void) {
    
    if let unwrappedDataOfJSON: Data = dataOfJSON {

        do {
            let value: T = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: unwrappedDataOfJSON)
            decodedValue(value)
        } catch {
            print("The Data could not be decoded!")
        }
    }
}
```

use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array: [String] = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {

        List {
 
            ForEach(array, id:\.self) { item in
                
                Text(item)
                
            }

        }
        .animation(.default, value: array)

        Button("load JSON") {
            
            decoderFunction(dataOfJSON: dataOfJSON, decodedValue: { (value: Brand) in

                array = value.results

            })
            
        }
    }
}
```